# Closed Loop Stepper Motor/Driver

Tags: motor-controller, stepper-driver, motion

I have been tasked with building a motion control demo box. The controller MUST include an Omron Delta Tau Power PMAC ([CK3W-AX1515P](https://automation.omron.com/en/us/products/family/CK3M)).

I can be flexible with the other components (motors, drivers, etc.) as long as they can be controlled with the selected controller. The plan was to use this [closed loop stepper](https://www.omc-stepperonline.com/closed-loop-stepper-motor/nema-17-closed-loop-stepper-motor-26ncm-36-83oz-in-encoder-1000ppr-4000cpr.html) and this [driver from Stepper Online](https://www.omc-stepperonline.com/closed-loop-stepper-driver/closed-loop-stepper-driver-0-30a-24-48vdc-for-nema-11-14-17-stepper-motor).

The question: Since the encoder would be plugged directly into the stepper driver, would there be any way for the controller to use this signal? Would it be better to purchase a standard open loop digital stepper driver and connect the encoder directly into the controller instead?

Comment: For industrial stuff like this, you should start by calling the manufacturer and getting their recommendation. Being able to talk to an engineer is one of the primary reasons for paying the huge markup on industrial components. Because your requirements are so minimal, they should be able to recommend components for you to buy, but if they can't they should at least be able to explain to you the interface requirements.

Comment: This site is intended for EE design and theory questions, not advice on what to buy. I am voting to close the question. You may want to contact a local distributor of the Omron product.

Comment: Great advice! Thanks!